# Publish Open Graph Story on timeline android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm doing a `Request` where the path is `/me/<app_namespace>:<action>` using the `Request` object on android like this:

```
MyOpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(MyOpenGraphAction.class);
MyGraphObject object = GraphObject.Factory.create(MyGraphObject.class);

object.setUrl("<myurl>");
action.setMyObject(object);

Request request = new Request(session, "me/myapp:myaction", null, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
request.setGraphObject(action);
new RequestAsyncTask(request).execute();
```

This is my graphObject and action definition:

```
private interface MyGraphObject extends GraphObject {
    public String getUrl();
    public void setUrl(String url);

    public String getId();
    public void setId(String id);
}
private interface MyOpenGraphAction extends OpenGraphAction {
    public MyGraphObject getMyObject();
    public void setMyObject(MyGraphObject  myObject);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't give any error; but the action is not posted on the timeline.

Comment: I'm assuming the getMyObject and setMyObject matches the property name you gave to the object in your action definition? (i.e. setMyObject would translate to the property being "my_object").

Comment: I changed the names so they would match and it worked, but the problem now is that the image I'm trying to upload via a `Bundle` is not appearing on the user timeline. It has the `user_generated` and the `fb:explicity_shared`. I'm getting the byte array out of a `ByteOutputStream`  and then pass it to the `Bundle` using the key 'image' as in   `params.putByteArray("image",data);`  is that the correct key?

Comment: is there any documentation where I can read how to properly create an OpenGraphAction and a GraphObject in order to send the data and the image?  Facebook's one is pretty incomplete, I tried searching for about 3 days now, but I can't find any examples

Comment: You can't upload an image to your me/<app_namespace>:<action> endpoint. You need to POST it to me/staging_resources first. See this how-to on using the Object API (specifically step 3 for image uploading) - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/share-using-object-api/

Comment: Ok I think understand now. So I have to create an object using a JSONObject that will contains the properties that I set in the object's html meta tags. Then make a request with params.putString("object",jsonObject); to the path: "me/objects/?" what would be that path?

Comment: I followed the tutorial but I'm getting an error "Unsupported Post Request", what am I doing wrong?